# modify only one column of a big file and keep field seperator the same in unix

Tags: unix, tabs, awk, field

I have a very big file (more than 10000 columns). I would like to change 3 entries in the second column and keep anything else the same, including the field separator.

For example:

```
ab123\t123\t0.1
ab234\t120\t0.5
```

I would like to check if the second column has the entry 120 and change it 1201 and keep everything else the same.

I tried awk. It works fine but replaces the tab delimited with space.

```
awk '{ if ( $2 == 120 ) { $2 = 1201 }; print}' file
```

How can i do this without losing the tab delimited version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to set `FS` *(field separator)* and `OFS` *(output field separator)* to tabs:

```
awk '$2==120{$2=1201}1' FS='\t' OFS='\t' file
```

`OFS` is the important variable here as `awk` uses it's value to separate the fields on output.

**EDIT:**

The structure of `awk` is `conditional{block}`, if the conditional is evaluated TRUE then the block is executed. So with `$2==120{$2=1201}` the conditional is `$2==120` if the second field is the value 120 and the block is `{$2=1201}` assign the second field the value 1201. The default block in `awk` is `{print $0}` so:

```
awk '$2==120{$2=1201}{print $0}'
```

Can be re-written as:

```
awk '$2==120{$2=1201}1'
```

Where 1 is the conditional which always evaluates to TRUE and because we don't specify a block the default `{print $0}` is executed.

For multiple conditions just add more structures *i.e:*

```
awk '$2==120{$2=1201}$3==130{$3==1301}1'
```

This is more of an `if` `if` structure as both block can be executed and `if` `else` would use the `next` statement to jump to next line in the file *i.e:*

```
 awk '$2==120{$2=1201;next}{$2==1202}1'
```

If the first block is executed here the second field is takes the value 1201 and we grab the next line else the second field will take the value 1202. So the second field will always take a new value, either `1201` or `1202`.

An `if` `elif` would be:

```
awk '$2==120{$2=1201;next}$3==130{$3==1301}1'
```

Here the second field may take a new value, if it does the third field will not be updated even if the condition is true because it never get evaluated. The third field can only be updated if the first condition is FALSE and the second TRUE.

Comment: Thanks @sudo_O, can you also please explain me what it does. What does 1 do? Don't you need the if condition anywhere? and also how can I extend this to more than one condition? something equivalent to 'if - else if'?

Comment: also @sudo_O, is there a way of checking whether the field separator is tab delimited or not rather than visual inspect?

Comment: @user1007742 I'm not quite sure what you mean, if you want to see visually the tabs in a file then you can do `cat -T file` this will show the tabs as `^I`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 sed -r 's/^ *[^ ]+ +120\b/\01/' file
```

Comment: hi @sidharth c nadhan, thanks. would this not search and replace in the whole file rather than the second column only?

Comment: One and only one set of spaces are allowed before 120 in the regex. This ensures that it replaces only in the second column.